How can I change the color of a row depending on the value of either of two cells?
I have a checklist-style Excel sheet that I work with every year. The sheet tracks the status of the yearly reports from our satellite offices. I have one column that shows what date the items were received, and one that tracks when their payment for the year is sent.
I'd like to somehow get the sheet to turn the row red if either date is after 7/1 of that year. I also need the row to turn green if the column that tracks if all their items are received says Y. (Late would be any date after 7/1 of the year I am using it.) Basically red would depend on either of two variables, and green would depend on just one. They also need to stay red if either date is late, regardless of the received item status.
I've already got it set up to turn green if the column tracking all items in is Y, using conditional formatting. I can't figure out how to add to it to get lines red as well. I'm probably just missing a step or need to make a macro. Thanks for any help in advance. :)
I've tried conditional formatting, but that only got the lines turning green automatically. Also the conditional formatting would only work for just one variable. I'm not great with coding in Excel, so I haven't tried that yet. I'm not against it, just don't have much practice or need for it at work.

What should happen if the date is exactly 7/1? Can you show us the formula you have tried in your conditional formatting?

This can be a kind of approach you can apply.
You need to calculate the condition summary in the dedicated column and define conditional formatting basing on it:

Here you can note another way for multiple formatting. You can define several formatting rules for a range. They can be applied in order shown in this window. And you need to mark "Stop if true" checkboxes to allow rules to be applied to the single formatting parameter.
E. g.:

Green if condition #2 is TRUE, stop if true, otherwise
Red if condition #1 is TRUE, stop if true, otherwise
Yellow if condition #3 is TRUE.

This is illustrated below:

You can change the order of conditions to adjust the formatting logic.
